# Using ST_Project with PostGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, postgis-2.0

I can't understand the results of ST_Project:

- I use geography-type here, but the results are the same for geometry.
- I use a rather long distance, because I need, at least in one direction, for my application a large distance. Because of this I found the problem in the first place.

I just want to project a point towards North, East, South and West.
With the direction north, everything is as I expect it:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Project('POINT(-30 -0.5)'::geography, 1e7, radians(0)));
      st_astext          
-----------------------------
POINT(-30 89.4874128664049)
```

But in the other directions, here for example East, I get this:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Project('POINT(-30 -0.5)'::geography, 1e7, radians(90)));
              st_astext                  
---------------------------------------------
POINT(59.8315233716443 0.00116689648502556)
```

I think this should be `POINT(59.8315233716443 -0.5)`

This behaviour occurs in all directions save north.

I'm new to whole earth coordinate systems so maybe I missed something, but I thought that when one walks directly west (or south) one would, by definition, not leave the current longitude (or latitude)-line but only change the other.

Answer (score 3):

Straight lines on the sphere (paths you achieve by moving straight and not turning) are not lines of constant bearing, with only a couple exceptions (north/south meridians and the equator).

ST_Project projects along a great circle (a straight line in spherical terms), starting with the given bearing.

Lines of latitude (except the equator) are not great circles, so projecting directly east and west will *not* land you at a position on the same line of latitude.